# How can I use a bucket as a variable within my Terraform bucket policy?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a list of S3 buckets and limit access to them to one user.  That user should only have access to that bucket and no permissions to do other things in AWS.

I created my list as so (bucket names are not real in this example):

```
// List bucket names as a variable
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type    = "list"
  default = [
    "myfirstbucket", 
    "mysecondbucket", 
    ...
    ]
}
```

Then I create a user.

```
// Create a user
resource "aws_iam_user" "aws_aim_users" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  name          = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"  
  path = "/"
}
```

I then create an access key.

```
// Create an access key
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "aws_iam_access_keys"  {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  user          = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  // user = "${aws_iam_user.aws_aim_user.name}"
}
```

Now I create a user policy
// Add user policy

```
resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "aws_iam_user_policies" {
  // user = "${aws_iam_user.aws_aim_user.name}"
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  name          = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  user          = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                 ...
            ],
            "Resource": "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index].arn}}"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Now I create my buckets with the user attached.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "aws_s3_buckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"
  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Id": "Policy1574607242703",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1574607238413",
        "Action": [
          "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": {
          "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index].arn}}"
          "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index].arn}/*}"
        },
        "Principal": {
         "AWS": "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}" 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
POLICY  

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
    Environment = "live"
}
}
```

The problem I have is it doesn't like where I have set the ARN in the policy by using my variable.

I also believe I need to use the user.arn not the bucket, although they should have the same name.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think I see a few things that might be able to help you out.

The bucket policy resource options aren't going to use the arn of the bucket, they're looking for the actual bucket name so it would look like this "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket".

I also see a few extra }'s in your setup there which could also be causing problems.

and,,, terraform is on version 0.12 which removes the need for the {$"resource.thing"} and replaces it with resource.thing instead. They have a helpful `terraform 0.12upgrade` command to run that upgrades the files which is nice. With terrafor 0.12 they adjusted how the resource creation like you have is being done. https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/

Comment: I would also add IMO I'd make it so the users and buckets didn't share the same name, so I would have it be `"${user.bucket}-user"` or something like that

Comment: Thanks @CMiller can you tell me why you would do it that way?

Comment: To me, it just seems like a best practice sort of thing. I could see myself or someone getting confused down the line if buckets and users shared the same name. From what it sounds like you're setting it up so one user will only have access to one bucket which makes sense why you'd set it up as a user and bucket having the same name.

Comment: Fair comment and white easy to implement. I think it's s good shout. I'll do that.